# Android Databinding Formatter with org.threeten.bp.OffsetDateTime

Tags: java, android, android-databinding

I have an `OffsetDateTime` from the `org.threeten:threetenbp` package that I would like to format in my Android view.

I have a DTO:

```
public class SomeDto {
    private org.threeten.bp.OffsetDateTime timestamp;
    // getters and setters...
}
```

And a view with a binding and TextView:

```
<data>
    <variable
        name="dto"
        type="com.example.SomeDto" />
</data>
...
<TextView
        ...
        android:text="@{@string/formatTime(dto.timestamp)}"
 />
```

And a `strings.xml`:

```
<string name="formatTime">%1$tH:%1$tM</string>
```

But I can't seem to get it to work. I get:

```
 java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: H != org.threeten.bp.OffsetDateTime
```

The Android docs detail the formatter [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Formatter#dt).

I can make the formatter work with strings. But no matter what date/time formatting I put in `strings.xml`, I get the above exception.

Does formatting simply not work with `OffsetDateTime`?

Comment: tried custom [binding adapter](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/binding-adapters)?

Comment: At first I tried `@BindingConversion`, but that's a bit too global.

Solved it with a custom `@BindingAdapter`. Thanks.

Comment: sure, your welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @pskink commented on above, I used a `BindingAdapter`:

```
@BindingAdapter("formatTime")
public static void formatTime(TextView textView, OffsetDateTime dateTime) {
    textView.setText(dateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedTime(FormatStyle.MEDIUM)));
}
```

And then in my view:

```
<TextView
    ...
    formatTime="@{dto.timestamp}"
/>
```